# Range calculation when the variables are not making a symmetric equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If consider a situation where equations given is not symmetric , that is $a+2b+c = 4$ and $ab + bc +2ca = 8$ , we know the method to find range : that is by making a quadratic , but my query is that here as the equations are not fully symmetric ,so the range we get for a variable say $"a"$ , will it be same range of "$b$" too ? If not how to find the different range of all three , though by intuition we can say range of $a$ and $c$ to be equal as both are similar

Comment: The terms domain and range only properly apply to functions; neither of these equations is a function. If you use a more generalized idea of a "domain/range" for each variable, I don't see how that wouldn't likely be $\mathbb{R}$ for all of $a,b,c$.

Comment: Following on, I suspect if you toss $xy + yz + 2xz - 2x -4y -2z = 0$ into your favorite 3D graphing program, you'll get a sense of the "domain/ranges."

Comment: And now having gone and done the thing I recommended, I stand corrected. I was fully expecting $xy+yx+2xz =8$ to avoid the axes, but I was expecting more than two sheets. Its intersection with the plane $x+2y+z=4$ is actually a single parabola, as opposed to the multiple curves I was expecting. Assuming Geogebra is correct, which might be a poor assumption, but probably not...

Comment: I understand ,  by range calculation what i meant was that the all possible values the variables may take . So if you can may you give a method for that Sir?

Comment: Unfortunately, I know of no method other than what I did, i.e. brute force. I don't even know how to solve for the parametric equation of the intersection--only saw that via graphing it.